# Windows Explorer Touch Interface

Tags: windows-10-v1703

I overheard someone talking about trying out a new touchscreen enabled version of Windows Explorer recently released.  Apparently, it's hidden in the Creators Update.

Where can I find it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run the following (perhaps in a shortcut):

explorer shell:AppsFolder\c5e2524a-ea46-4f67-841f-6a9465d9d515_cw5n1h2txyewy!App

http://www.askvg.com/review-hidden-secret-file-explorer-app-in-windows-10/

Oh, and it's now called **File Explorer**